# HTML Canvas overlapping polygon heatmap

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6

I have several hundred polygon layers, and I needed to know which ones overlap, and shade the overlapping area darker/brighter similar to a heat-map. I have tried the property: "_ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply'", but that doesn't quite work since it does apply it to every layer, not just the overlapping ones.

I am not sure where to start regarding which formulas to use to investigate something like this. I have found some libraries handle this like: http://fabricjs.com/intersection, have it built in.

I have a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/v6swarb7/2/

```
       const _canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const _ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const poly1 = [[172.87066184227245, 40.37854538483082], [172.87066184227245, 66.87696924040097], [13.880126229942462, 66.87696924040097], [13.880126229942462, 106.62460502375617], [119.87381413113218, 106.62460502375617], [119.87381413113218, 80.12618116818604], [146.37223798670232, 80.12618116818604], [146.37223798670232, 133.12302699905362], [186.11987377005755, 133.12302699905362], [186.11987377005755, 40.37854538483082], [172.87066184227245, 40.37854538483082]];
    const poly2 = [[13.880126229942462, 66.87696924040097], [13.880126229942462, 106.62460502375617], [119.87381413113218, 106.62460502375617], [119.87381413113218, 66.87696924040097], [13.880126229942462, 66.87696924040097]];
    _ctx.beginPath();
    /* _ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply'; */
    poly1.map((val, i) => {
        _ctx.lineTo(
            val[0], val[1]
        )
        _ctx.stroke();
    });
    _ctx.closePath();

    _ctx.beginPath();
    poly2.map(val => {
        // this fill would be dynamic, and get gradually darker the more that overlap.
        _ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        _ctx.lineTo(
            val[0], val[1]
        )
        _ctx.fill();
        _ctx.stroke();
    });
    _ctx.closePath();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using a globalAlpha to see what overlaps, but after feedback, we truly need to detect pixels that overlap polygons, to do that we `getImageData` and analyze all the pixels to see which are inside the polygons, I'm just make them black on this case, but I guess you can do other logic to color them as you prefer.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.6

  const poligons = [
    [[89, 9], [13, 9], [13, 76], [98, 36], [89, 9]],
    [[5, 50], [5, 90], [99, 90], [99, 50], [5, 50]]
  ]

  function draw(poly, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    poly.map(val => ctx.lineTo(val[0], val[1]));
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function inside(p, vs) {
    var inside = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
      var xi = vs[i][0], yi = vs[i][1];
      var xj = vs[j][0], yj = vs[j][1];
      var intersect = ((yi > p[1]) != (yj > p[1])) && (p[0] < (xj - xi) * (p[1] - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
      if (intersect) inside = !inside;
    }
    return inside;
  };

  function check_overlap(p) {
    for (x = 0; x < p.width; x++) {
      for (y = 0; y < p.height; y++) {
        let overlap = 0
        for (pol = 0; pol < poligons.length; pol++) {
          if (inside([x, y], poligons[pol]))
            overlap++
        }
        if (overlap >= 2) {
          offset = (p.width * y + x) * 4;
          p.data[offset] = 0;
          p.data[offset + 1] = 0;
          p.data[offset + 2] = 0;

        }
      }
    }
    return p
  }

  draw(poligons[0], 'blue')
  draw(poligons[1], 'red')

  data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  data = check_overlap(data);
  ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, and your example is much clearer, then my own. 

The problem with globalAlpha, and globalCompositeOperation is they both apply "globally" to all canvas layers. Certain "base layers" shouldn't have any sort of transparency.

An ideal solution would allow me to just target the overlapping piece between them, and make it brighter/darker.

Comment: I see what you mean... so is not just visually displaying the overlaps but you want to check that pixels overlap ... this can get tricky with several hundred of polygon layers but you can loop over all pixel and if  pixel is in more than one we can declare it an overlap ... let's see if I can put a sample

Comment: Take a look at my latest, I added some logic to detect overlap

Comment: You sir are my hero. This makes sense to me, and going pixel to pixel is probably faster than going by each layer. Thank you for your help!! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad you like it, now... going pixel to pixel yes, but we do check against each layer/polygon, see `function check_overlap` there are 3 loops so the amount of layers will impact performance